# Problem with Java InputStream's read method not reading the first few bytes

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, inputstream

So, i have written a simple program, that receives a text file and is meant to output the characters within the file one by one on separate lines.

Below is the content of the "hello.txt" text file that I'm using:

```
Hello How Are You?
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class input_stream {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\m3hran\\Desktop\\file_test\\hello.txt");

        byte[] byteArray = new byte[1024];

        int ArraysRead = input.read(byteArray);

        input.close();

        System.out.println(ArraysRead);

        for (byte i : byteArray) {
            System.out.println ((char) i);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that my output seems to be skipping the first few bytes for some reason - here is my output:

[image]

I was wondering if anyone knows what's causing this issue? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I doubt that is your entire output.  Surely `System.out.println(ArraysRead);` printed a number as well, which might help explain the bytes which are printed.

Comment: I just compiled the program manually and ran it using CMD and it show cased the entire output including the number of bytes read. Is there any reason why VS code is not showing the full ouput?

Comment: The screenshot i included is the entirety of the output when I run my program in VS code.

Comment: VS Code usually has a scrollable and resizable output window. Maybe you just need to scroll up or resize the output window.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the case for me here, but thank you for the help. As long as I know my code works as intended its fine.

Comment: there was once an issue with vsc check here [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85010) Probably is an extension error. Disable some and check the behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running the file at the first time, i got the same result as yours which was post in question, but after enlarging the Terminal and run the file again, the result would be shown correctly, which is as the same as the one in external Terminal:
[image]

It seems to be an issue which could be put in github and here's my issue link: [Can't show complete java result in Terminal unless resize it](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-pack/issues/555).

Besides, please pay attention to your privacy protection and you may cover the name in your screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be problem with your code, but I'd suggest using try-with-resources and initializing arrays with the length that you actually need

```
String filePath = "C:\\Users\\m3hran\\Desktop\\file_test\\hello.txt";
File file = new File(filePath);

try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)){
    
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    int bytesRead = fis.read(bytes);
        
    for (byte i : bytes) {
        System.out.println((char) i);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

also from Java7 you can just use `Files::readAllBytes`

```
String filePath = "C:\\Users\\m3hran\\Desktop\\file_test\\hello.txt";
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File(filePath));
for (byte i : bytes) {
    System.out.println((char) i);
}
```

Comment: Why use an external library when you can just use `Files.readAllLines()` from the standard lib?

Comment: Just a habit, of course `Files::readAllBytes` will work as well, going to replace it.. Thanks for the note.

Comment: @daniu however `Files.readAllBytes` is Java9 while the Apache Commons one is from Java7, but I guess he's not in a situation where he's forced to use a certain JDK

Comment: Nope, `Files` is Java 7 as well. Actually (found when checking), it even has a [`readAllBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)) method.

Comment: @daniu I stand corrected https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Answer (score 0):

code below print too many lines and your console has maximum lines limit

```
    for (byte i : byteArray) {
            System.out.println ((char) i);
        }
```

you could try

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\m3hran\\Desktop\\file_test\\hello.txt");

        byte[] byteArray = new byte[1024];

        int len = input.read(byteArray);

        input.close();

        System.out.println(new String(Arrays.copyOf(byteArray,len)));
    }
```